# Getting Null model when POST from angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, http-post

**Here is my angular Call** 
When POST date from here on controller side model return NULL.

```
self.saveZone = function (data) {
    var jdata = JSON.stringify(data);
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        url: glogal.endpoint + 'Zone/ZoneSave',
        data: jdata
    })
};
```

**And this is my controller api code** 
Here Model get null value.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ZoneSave([FromBody]  Zone model)
    {
    var result = await zoneManager.SaveZone(model);

        return Ok(new { success = result == "success" });
    }
```

Comment: Be clearer : you have a **null** value on the Angular side, or on the .NET side ?

Comment: Post value from Angular side get null model from .NET side

Comment: Then you send **null** data. Try not sending **null** data. Do a `console.log(jdata)` to see it.

Comment: I got the data in jdata

Comment: Then your problem is in the .NET section, thus not related to AngularJS, so I can't help you. Sorry !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (with a PHP backend but no matter)
It seems to be depending on the version of AngularJS you are using.

I haven't find any proper solution for now, but passing my data into headers variables (after `'Content-type'` ) was working for me... and sufficient for my needs at the moment.

Comment: This is dirty, isn't it ?

Comment: This is really dirty, I agree! I'm not saying you should use it, I'm saying it's a bad working solution until something clean :)